# Syncfusion Cartesian chart - Categorical XAxis gridline on every other value

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

In a syncfusion cartesian chart, how can I customize the xaxis `CategoryAxis` in order to make the grid line appear on every other entry.

For example if its a monthly earnings line chart, I want the grid lines to appear on every other month so: feb, apr, jun etc...

I tried setting the interval to 2 but that hides the rest of the months, I want them all to apear.

Here is my `CategoryAxis` code:

```dart
primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
        maximumLabels: 12,
        labelStyle: FontStyles.secondSmallInfo?.apply(
          color: mainWhite,
          fontSizeFactor: 0.4,
        ),
        labelPlacement: LabelPlacement.onTicks,
        axisLine: AxisLine(
          color: mainGrey,
          width: 0.8,
        ),
        majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(
          width: 0.4,
          color: mainGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
          dashArray: const [10, 5],
        ),
        majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(
          width: 0.8,
          color: mainGrey.withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
      ),
```

And here is a screenshot of the current output

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that you need to render the gridline with the interval of two axis labels and there is no option to render the gridline with the specified interval with all the axis labels visible. However, you can be able to achieve the mentioned requirement using the [plotBands](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/ChartAxis/plotBands.html) property and the [plotBands](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/ChartAxis/plotBands.html) will be repeated for the specified interval given to the [repeatEvery](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/PlotBand/repeatEvery.html) property.

Kindly refer the code snippet below:

```
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  late List<ChartSampleData> _data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _data = [
      ChartSampleData('JAN', 80),
      ChartSampleData('FEB', 50),
      ChartSampleData('MAR', 60),
      ChartSampleData('APR', 20),
      ChartSampleData('MAY', 40),
      ChartSampleData('JUN', 30),
      ChartSampleData('JUL', 60),
      ChartSampleData('AUG', 70),
      ChartSampleData('SEP', 40),
      ChartSampleData('OCT', 90),
      ChartSampleData('NOV', 10),
      ChartSampleData('DEC', 40),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SfCartesianChart(
          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
            plotBands: <PlotBand>[
              PlotBand(
                size: 0,
                repeatEvery: 2,
                repeatUntil: 12,
                borderWidth: 0.4,
                isVisible: true,
                isRepeatable: true,
                dashArray: const [10, 5],
                borderColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ],
            maximumLabels: 12,
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
            labelPlacement: LabelPlacement.onTicks,
            axisLine: const AxisLine(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 0.8,
            ),
            majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
              width: 0,
            ),
            majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(
              width: 0.8,
              color: Colors.purpleAccent,
            ),
          ),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(),
          series: <CartesianSeries<ChartSampleData, String>>[
            ColumnSeries<ChartSampleData, String>(
              dataSource: _data,
              xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, int index) => sales.x,
              yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, int index) => sales.y,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Snapshot:
[Column Series Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlKQN.jpg)

Shared the UserGuide documentation link below regarding the PlotBand for your reference.

PlotBand : https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-customization#plot-bands.

We recommend you check and modify the shared code snippet according to your needs.